# How to hide/un-hide a file without erasing other attributes in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, filesystems

I would like to be able to hide/un-hide a file in Windows in C++, but I was concerned about erasing other attributes (like FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE, ...).

Here is the current code:

```
//Hiding the file
SetFileAttributes(path, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);

// Un-Hiding the file
SetFileAttributes(path, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
```

This works fine for regular files, but will hiding the file remove a READONLY flag for example? Will unhiding the file remove it?

If yes, I was planning on doing something like this:

```
//Hiding the file
int attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
if ((attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0) {
    SetFileAttributes(path, attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}

//Unhiding the file
int attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
if ((attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) {
    SetFileAttributes(path, attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Would that work?

Comment: One minor thing: don't forget to check `GetFileAttributes` return value (check whether it equals `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This test won't work, it will always be false:

```
if ((attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0)
```

It should instead say

```
if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0)
```

Similarly, to test if a file is already hidden:

```
if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
```

Final corrected code:

```
//Hiding the file
int attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0) {
    SetFileAttributes(path, attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}

//Unhiding the file
int attr = GetFileAttributes(path);
if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) {
    SetFileAttributes(path, attr & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the first code will remove all other attributes.

The second code is almost correct, but you've missed `~` symbol:

```
// Hiding the file

int attr = GetFileAttributes(path);

if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0) {
    SetFileAttributes(path, attr | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}

// Unhiding the file

int attr = GetFileAttributes(path);

// Is it currently visible?
if ((attr & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) {
    SetFileAttributes(path, attr & ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: Be aware, though, that code like this, as all file operations, is very prone to race conditions with other processes accessing the same file..

Comment: The & operator is required in the if() statement.