# Hiding the folder from the windows explorer

Tags: mfc, windows-shell

I am looking to hide the folder from the explorer.
It should not be visible when someone unchecks the *show hidden file in folder* option.

Is there any Shell API to achieve this, or how do I achieve in MFC or win api or C++, etc? Any ideas and suggestions?

Comment: The Sony Rootkit did the trick, back in the day :).

Answer (score 0):

Use [SetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the flag `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`.  To ensure you don't accidentally clear other attributes you will want to read the directory attributes first using [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example:

```
void hidePath( const std::wstring& path )
{
    const DWORD attributes = GetFileAttributes( path.c_str() );
    SetFileAttributes( path.c_str(), attributes | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN );
}
```

Also see: [How to hide/un-hide a file without erasing other attributes in C++ on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387145/how-to-hide-un-hide-a-file-without-erasing-other-attributes-in-c-on-windows)

Comment: same thing i tried BOOL createFolder12 = CreateDirectory(temp,NULL);
SetFileAttributes(temp,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);this will again visible when the user click the show hidden file and folder in folder option of the windows

Comment: Your question says that you don't want it to be visible when "Show hidden files" is not checked.  Do you mean you don't want it to be visible when it is checked?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible using documented nor undocumented Shell API.

Comment: Then how one can achieve this.

Comment: Hooking from kernel mode is best solution for this.

Comment: Sorry to say what is Hooking from kernel mode  is it writing the file system driver for it.